# delete a line w.r.t a column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have this text file:

```
echo "Start 2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF 6420 6751" 
echo "dimensions 9249 49"  
echo "New Cell"   
grep "6449,34" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 19.01  11.13  72.53 291
echo "New Cell"   
grep "6466,35" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 18.97  10.80  73.07 237
echo "New Cell"   
grep "6483,08" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 19.75   9.43  72.89 237
echo "New Cell"   
grep "6524,14" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 22.95   8.77  74.29 291
echo "New Cell"   
grep "6529,38" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 21.62   9.54  75.06 237
echo "New Cell"   
grep "6542,06" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 20.09   8.07  74.61 170
grep "6542,07" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 32.25   8.11  74.64 210
grep "6543,06" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 33.28   8.05  74.64 210
grep "6543,07" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 43.38   8.09  74.67 210
grep "6543,08" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.22   8.13  74.70 210
grep "6544,06" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 35.81   8.03  74.67 210
grep "6544,07" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 41.58   8.07  74.70 200
grep "6545,06" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 36.3   8.01  74.70 120
grep "6545,07" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 31.57   8.05  74.73 210
grep "6546,06" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 28.49   7.99  74.73 292
echo "New Cell"   
grep "6552,03" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 18.92   7.74  74.83 237
echo "New Cell"   
grep "6560,10" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 23.2   7.83  75.26 291
echo "New Cell"   
grep "6562,21" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 26.74   8.19  75.61 210
grep "6563,20" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 26.35   8.13  75.62 210
grep "6563,21" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 42.51   8.17  75.64 200
grep "6563,22" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 25.82   8.20  75.67 210
grep "6564,20" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 23.08   8.11  75.65 272
grep "6564,21" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 46.55   8.15  75.67 200
grep "6564,22" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 36.89   8.18  75.70 200
grep "6565,21" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 31.61   8.12  75.70 200
grep "6565,22" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 28.85   8.16  75.73 120
echo "New Cell"   
                                                                                                                             23,1          Top
```

I want to delete the ROWS in which Column 8 (Number 200, 210, 120) is less than 200, But the New Cell has to be retained. 
I have tried awk like this:

```
awk '{if ($8 >= 200) print $0}' CSWoSpix.apr2009.sh >OUT1
```

But it does not retain the echo "New Cell " lines.

Comment: please format your question, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help and add complete expected output for given sample input for clarity

Comment: echo "Start 2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF 6420 6751" 
echo "dimensions 9249 49"  
echo "New Cell" grep "6542,07" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 32.25   8.11  74.64 210
grep "6543,06" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 33.28   8.05  74.64 210
grep "6543,07" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 43.38   8.09  74.67 210
grep "6543,08" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.22   8.13  74.70 210
grep "6544,06" out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 35.81   8.03  74.67 210

 is the expected O/p

Answer (score 1):

To print a line if it either has field 8 greater than 200 or if it contains the phrase `New Cell`, try:

```
awk '{if ($8 >= 200 || /New Cell/) print $0}' filename
```

Because print is awk's default action, the above can be simplified to:

```
awk '$8 >= 200 || /New Cell/' filename
```